# 1.7.4 Ender Chest disappeared

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made 2 ender chests put one in my base and 1 in my mine I then quit the game when I came back the 1 in my mine was gone. I requit and came back it was still gone. I know it was there because I checked in side it to take something out before I left.

Comment: Is this in single-player or multi-player? Are you running any sort of backup service (for instance, are you storing your maps in a DropBox folder?)

Comment: This is single player. And no I am not running any backup service.

Comment: Try putting a block where the ender-chest was, and see if MineCraft lets you; perhaps it's just a rendering issue.

Comment: I already tried that it is not a rendering problem that I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you misplaced it yourself. There are no issues reporting disappearing enderchests at all from the community. That leaves two options: most likely, you messed up. 
Less likely, you found a new bug and you should try to recreate it and report this issue as a bug.

Anyway, once you made your first enderchest it is a cakewalk to make multiples of these. You did not report you lost items and i think this is highly unlikely, so why not just craft a new chest and place it again? This would solve your current problem.